# CreateProcessAsUser not working correctly in my experiments

Tags: createprocessasuser

I am trying to do the following:
1. I am logged in as Administrator account in my XP with SP2 machine running VS.NET 2005
2. This machine also has another account user1 which is a guest account
3. I am running a program as Administrator, from this program i want to launch a notepad.exe process which will be running under the user1 security context
4. I specifically want to use `CreateProcessasUser` to do this..

This is the code snipper which will explain what i have been trying..

```
const string GRANTED_ALL = "10000000";

const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
static IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
static IntPtr hTokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int last_error = 0;
    if(LogonUser("user1",null,"#welcome123",
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out hToken))
    {
        last_error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        last_error = 0;
        last_error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if(DuplicateTokenEx(hToken,UInt32.Parse(GRANTED_ALL,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
            ref sa,SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
            TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,out hTokenDuplicate))
        {
            last_error = 0;
            last_error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            CreateProcessAsUser(hTokenDuplicate, "d:\\san\\notepad.exe", null,
            ref sa, ref sa, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, "d:\\san", ref si, out pi);

            last_error = 0;
            last_error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        }
    }

    last_error = 0;
    last_error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();


    if (hToken != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(hToken);
    if (hTokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(hTokenDuplicate);

}
```

For some reason this is not working..
The `DuplicateTokenEx` function is returning as error code of 1305 and i cant seem to figure out why..

Instead of `DuplicateTokenEx` i also used the `DuplicateToken`, now the `CreateProcessAsUser` is returning an error code of 1308.

Could someone please throw light on this issue.. This appears to be an apparently very simple thing, but just cant get it right..
[Please note that I specifically want to `LogonUser` and then `DuplicateToken` and then `CreateProcessAsUSer`]

Answer (score -2):

See [CreateProcessAsUser() windowstations and desktops](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165194).

But I suggest to do it in managed way:

```
...
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;
...
...
string progPath = @"c:\WINNT\notepad.exe";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(progPath);
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.UserName = "SomeUser";
SecureString password = new SecureString();

#region setting password
password.AppendChar('p');
password.AppendChar('a');
...
#endregion

startInfo.Password = password;
Process.Start(startInfo);
...
...
```